# CSS: how to create a fixed top header with a fixed width

Tags: css

I have following fixed top header using this class:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Now, I would like to have a fixed width `840px`, not 100% and centered as shown in this [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jobgaraux/yv3hykLo/2/).

Comment: What do you want to fix fixed with? The header or the content?

Comment: Setting fixed pixel sizes will generally make for very poor performance on different screens and devices. Relative sizing is so much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    width: 840px;
    margin-left: -420px
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
}
```

This is the solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dynamic solution, using [`transform: translateX(-50%)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#funcdef-translatex) - ([demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/zuym1wrj/)):

```
.sticky {
    left:50%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    transform:translate(-50%);
    width:840px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

I wouldn't recommend to use a static solution but you can use it too ([demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/5njf9b9n/)):

```
.sticky {
    left:calc(50% - 420px);
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:840px;
    z-index:100;
}
```

**Why you should avoid a static solution?**

You can define many items like this to set the position of these, but if you change the width in future you have to change the static part of the CSS definitions too. You can't totally avoid using static parts on CSS but you can minimize them!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try something like this ?

HTML :

```
 <div class="sticky-container">
    <div class="nav sticky">
      Navigation
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS :

```
.sticky-container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 840px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
}
.sticky {
  position:relative;
  left:-50%;
  top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your .sticky class to the below:

```
.sticky {
  margin:auto;
    width: 840px;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
}
```

and remove that top margin on body:

```
body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: It should be fixed (in the viewport, not in the page) thus centering with `margin: auto` won't work here